# Taylor series expansion of $\sin (\sin (x))$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

I was attempting a question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2633081/571692)

> Evaluate:
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin{(\sin{x})}-\sin^2{x}}{x^6}$$

And the answers involved the expansion of $\sin(\sin(x))$. While the coefficients for $x$ and $x^3$ match with my attempt, unfortunately, the coefficient of $x^5$ doesn't:

> $$\sin(\sin (x))=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac {x^5}{10} + O(x^6)$$

**My attempt:**

$$S(x)= \sin(\sin(x)) =\left (\sin x -\frac{\sin^3 x}{6} +\cdots\right )$$

Now using the expansion for $\sin x$,
$$S(x)=\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\cdots\right)-\frac 16\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+\cdots\right)^3+\cdots$$

Evaluating this gives me
$$S(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3} +\frac{11x^5}{120} +O(x^6)$$

As I'm new to handling such stuff, could anyone please tell me where I missed a $\frac{x^5}{120}$?

P.S. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/384289/571692) post doesn't help me as it doesn't need the fifth power.

Comment: What happened to $\frac {(\sin x )^{5}} {5!}$?

Comment: You missed it directly in first line.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Ohh, I see now. I initially let that go because it would generate (useless) higher powers, but it also generates the missing $x^5/120$. Thanks!